# Check if Ransack params are empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I have the following code in my controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
   expose(:search) { search_books }
   expose(:search_results) { load_results }

   def search_books
      search = Book.ransack(params[:q])
      search.sorts = 'updated_at desc' if search.sorts.empty?
      search
   end

   def load_results
      search.result(distinct: true)
   end
end
```

In my view I have lots of ransack search fields setup for the various book attributes i.e. `title_eq`,  `body_cont` etc.

When I click the search button an the fields are empty Ransack still sends the params through the `q:` param, even when they're empty. i.e. `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"title_eq"=>"", "book_eq"=>""}` etc.

I've searched inside Ransack to see whether they have a method to tell whether the params are empty but I can't find one. What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: I am trying to determine *why* this is an issue. In my experience and a review of the [Code Base](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/main/lib/ransack/search.rb#L28) ransack will ignores conditions that are blank.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made the clearer: I have a partial that displays depending on whether any search attributes have been entered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are fine with removing all blank search parameters, then you can call [`compact_blank`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-compact_blank) to only return key/values from the `params` that have a value present.

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({q: { title: '', body: 'foobar'}})

params[:q].compact_blank
#=> #<ActionController::Parameters {"body"=>"foobar"} permitted: false>
```